# perl : how to sort lines in a file depending on the second field and update the same file

Tags: perl

### file : entries.txt

```
d1 t-waaa.html
a1 t-paaa.html
e1 t-waaa.html
c1 t-uaaa.html
b1 t-paaa.html
f1 t-paaa.html
```

---

### perl file check.pl

```
#! /bin/perl
$cur_file = $ARGV[0];  # here ARGV[0] is entries.txt
open (FILE, "< $cur_file") or die "cannot open file: $!";
@file_lines = <FILE>;

@lines = map $_->[1],
         sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
         map { my ($num) = /-\s*(\d+)/; [ $num, $_ ] } @file_lines;

print @lines;
```

---

i'm not getting the expected output. file is getting printed as it is.

### expected output :

```
a1 t-paaa.html
b1 t-paaa.html
f1 t-paaa.html
c1 t-uaaa.html
d1 t-waaa.html
e1 t-waaa.html
```

---

where the code went wrong, i'm no sure.

Comment: Always add `use strict` and `use warnings` to your scripts.

Comment: In the title, you mention "the second field", but it's not very clear from your question how fields are separated: are they separated by a dash, or by a space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `\d` matches a digit; you probably wanted to use `\w`, or `\S` or `[a-z]` instead.
- `<=>` compares numbers; you don't have numbers to compare but string. Use `cmp` instead.
- The second elements (`->[1]`) of your arrays contain the file names rather than the fields you want to compare. Use `->[0]` instead.

Overall, that gives you:

```
@lines = map $_->[1],
         sort { $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] }
         map { my ($num) = /\s+(\S+)/; [ $num, $_ ] } @file_lines;
```

Note that I've replaced `-\s*` by `\s+` since the title of your question mentions that you want to sort according to the second field, which seems to occur after a white-space character. Feel free to use `-\s*` if needed.

Comment: thanks! this small-small edits really helped my code to work.

Comment: @Kittu I have execute above code but i am not getting output as per your expectation. Can you please share your logic

Comment: @amitbhosale I've replaced the `\w` by a `\S` in the snippet; it should work better now.

Answer (score 1):

Above mentioned code is good. you can also use package  `use List::UtilsBy 'sort_by';`  please check https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::UtilsBy 'sort_by';
use Data::Printer;

my $cur_file =   "entries.txt";
open (FILE, "< $cur_file") or die "cannot open file: $!";
my @file_lines = <FILE>;
close(FILE);

my @lines = sort_by { (split(' ', $_))[1] } @file_lines;
p @lines;
```

> Output

```
perl sort.pl
[
    [0] "a1 t-paaa.html
",
    [1] "b1 t-paaa.html
",
    [2] "f1 t-paaa.html",
    [3] "c1 t-uaaa.html
",
    [4] "d1 t-waaa.html
",
    [5] "e1 t-waaa.html
"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since its a string compression, your code should look like this:

```
...
@lines = map $_->[1],
         sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] }
         map { my ($num) = /-\s*(\d+)/; [ $num, $_ ] } @file_lines;
...
```

Comment: Probably should be comparing the first elements of the arrayrefs, not the second.